# Tangent handles in Graph editor no longer can be moved

Tags: animation

I'm pretty new to blender- thing is ive been editing the ins and outs of tangent handles all day and obviously now something i've done means i can no longer edit the tangent handles- anything i do simply wants to move the key and the handles up or down or left or right- thats going to be no good when i want the curves to cycle well

I even opened a fresh blender- added a cube and transformed that- those handles were editable

ive tried the many tangent types too just to see if an auto tangent thing is being applied

any ideas?

Comment: hah

i had accidentally switched on proportional editing- more of buttons in the interface could really shine blue to act as a signifier

Comment: You should add this solution to the answer box below. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Good point man

I hear the blender community is polite and helpful

I had accidentally switched on proportional editing

One of the tiny buttons along the top of the GE